# When Installer Class Execute

Tags: magento2, setup-script, discussion

I am trying to Implement same thing Magento is doing when we run **web installer wizard.**

> Magento is creating sample data (Attributes, Products, Categories)
>   using **`Setup\SampleData\InstallerInterface`** [class](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableSampleData/Setup/Installer.php).

**I've tried same thing for creating atrtibute.**

But I failed I did same thing as core code.

Created **CSV** and setup script as They did.

But seems to be not working for me.

I checked on internet i can't find any topic related to `Setup\SampleData\InstallerInterface`

Hope any Mage Master will respond me here.

**PS: I'm doing this because I'm failing to create Product attribute with some default options as I mentioned [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230833/problems-while-creating-product-attribute-with-installdata).**

Thanks in Advance.